# IObservable<Task<T>> to IObservable<T> that only produces the latest T

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an observable stream `IObservable<Task<T>>` (call it stream `A`). From this stream, I wish to produce an `IObservable<T>` (stream `B`). If these were my only requirements, I believe it would be sufficient to say

```
streamB = streamA.Select(async x => await x).Select(x => x.Result);
```

The first `Select` I expect is truly asynchronous, in the sense that as the stream produces more `Task<T>` each would be awaited. The second `Select` however, will then "block" until each of the `Task<T>`s complete in order. If I'm thinking correctly here, there's no actual blocking going on though, because the second `Select` won't be entered until each async operation, respectively, in the first `Select` completes and resumes execution. The problem for me with this pattern is the fact that I must wait for each task to complete (i.e. succeed, fail or be cancelled) in the order that they arrive.

Consider this scenario: Assume I have two `Task<T>`s, `t1` and `t2`. `t1` arrives before `t2`. However, when `t2` arrives, `t1` has yet to complete, i.e. in a marble diagram

`stream A: -------------------t1-------------t2-------------------------------`

`async Select completion --------------------------t1-----------t2------------`

`stream B: -----------------------------------------------------t2.Result----`

In other words, the arrival of `t2` from stream A before the completion of `t1` essentially means that t1 should be ignored and not produced by stream B.

I have been able to solve this problem by using very imperative code and adding (too much) complexity, by passing the task to a special helper class that keeps track of all tasks that arrive, using an incrementing `long` to id each, then `await`ing each task and using callbacks that pass the id back to the helper class to tell it which `Task` has completed. If the id is "older" than the latest to arrive, the result is ignored.

I strongly feel I am over-complicating what on the surface appears as a simple problem. Is there no infrastructure or pattern to solve this kind of problem, either in `System.Reactive` or e.g. in TPL?

Comment: [`Channel.CreateBounded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel.createbounded) with `BoundedChannelFullMode.DropOldest` (and `Capacity=1` or another small integer)

Comment: But that would let you skip `t2` if `t3` arrived before `t1` processing finished.  It wouldn't abandon `t1` on arrival of `t2`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Neat, that might do it. Two questions though: 1) why would it not abandon `t1`? With `Capacity=1` and `DropOldest`, `t1` would be the oldest upon arrival of `t2`, no? 2) How to go from the channel reader to an observable stream?

Comment: You can't "abandon" a task.  If its implementation is monitoring a CancellationToken, then it can be cancelled, otherwise it will keep running.  Regarding the Channel, `t1` got read from the Channel in order to start processing.  So it isn't in the Channel queue to get overwritten.

Comment: I'm not abandoning it; it recovers on the stored context and its result is discarded if a newer task arrived before it completed.

Re. t1 - right that makes sense. Close but no cigar, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the query you need:

```
IObservable<T> streamB = streamA.Select(t => Observable.FromAsync(() => t)).Switch();
```

You should almost always avoid `.Select(async x => await x)` as it breaks the Rx contract allowing overlapping executions due to the `async` sending control back to the calling thread.

The normal way to turn an `IObservable<Task<T>>` to an `IObservable<T>` is to use `.SelectMany(t => Observable.FromAsync(() => t))`.

In your case, though, you want to throw away any currently computing values if a new task comes through. So this changes the query from `.SelectMany(t => Observable.FromAsync(() => t))` to `.Select(t => Observable.FromAsync(() => t)).Switch()`.

`.Switch()` turns an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` into `IObservable<T>` by only producing values from the latest inner observable produced by the outer observable. It effectively ignores all but the latest observable. Just what you need.

Here's a demonstration of this working:

```
void Main()
{
    IObservable<Task<long>> streamA = new []
    {
        ReturnDelayedAsync(1),
        ReturnDelayedAsync(42),
    }.ToObservable();
    
    IObservable<long> streamB = streamA.Select(t => Observable.FromAsync(() => t)).Switch();
    
    streamB.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
}

public async Task<long> ReturnDelayedAsync(long x)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0));
    return x;
}
```

That produces a single value of `42` on the console.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! I made a couple of attempts using `Switch` on a `task.AsObervable()` so I wasn't far off I guess. Question though: why do you say `async await` inside the `Select` breaks the RX contract? I agree that it would return control to the calling thread, but why would you get any overlapping execution? Does it have to do with the default IScheduler? I thought that the func in `Select(x => x.Result)` would execute on the same IScheduler (in this case the default) and that continuations could occur out of order but not overlap?

Comment: @AlexanderHøst - Calling `.Select(x => /* Do Something */)` will always ensure that each `Do Something` completes before the next one starts. With `.Select(async x => /* Await & Do Something */)` the next value can begin being processed as soon as an `await` is hit.

Comment: Ok, agree about overlapping executions, but still don't understand why it breaks the contract. Say two IO-bound tasks, t1 and t2 are awaited by the `Select` and neither have completed. Suddenly, t2 completes. What happens now? Won't just the next `Select(x => x.Result)` execute with x = t2 on the originally calling thread? Does this break the contract? (I can ask a new question if this is getting out of hand).

Comment: @AlexanderHøst - I'm trying to work a counter-example, but so far my tests are returning to the calling thread. I'll have to spend more time later on this. For now, I just avoid these things like the plague when there's a direct alternative in the box.